# Selecting distinct values of a column with specific values of other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, duplicates

I have the following dataset where ID has duplicates and other columns are categorical columns ranged from 0 t0 2. I'd like to select unique IDs with values of other columns that are not zero, if available. The data is as follows:

```
 ID      X     Y     R      Z 
  1      0     2     0      1
  1      0     2     0      0
  2      1     0     0      1
  3      1     1     0      1
  3      1     1     1      1
  4      0     0     1      0
  4      0     1     1      0
```

My favourite outcome is:

```
 ID      X     Y     R      Z 
  1      0     2     0      1
  2      1     0     0      1
  3      1     1     1      1
  4      0     1     1      0
```

I am using **dplyr** and **group_by**

Thank you!

Comment: baseR option `aggregate(. ~ ID, df1, max)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a condition with `if/else` after the `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(all(. == 0)) 0 
       else unique(.[. !=0])), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#     ID     X     Y     R     Z
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     2     0     1
#2     2     1     0     0     1
#3     3     1     1     1     1
#4     4     0     1     1     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), X = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Y = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), R = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Z = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: thanks, I can accept your answer in a few mins. I'll try your code and will be in touch, thanks again

Comment: @ akrun, could you please explain the part inside summarise?

Comment: @akrun.I am getting an error because I it has `unexpected bracket and unexpected comma` in the `summarise` part

Comment: @Alex I tested the code again.  Sorry, couldn't get the error you mentioned.  Is it because you have a different `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(rowSums(.SD != 0))], ID]
```

which gives

```
   ID X Y R Z
1:  1 0 2 0 1
2:  2 1 0 0 1
3:  3 1 1 1 1
4:  4 0 1 1 0
```